# High response duration on first request for .net core api on Azure

Tags: azure, .net-core, alwayson

I have deployed a .Net Core API to Azure as an App Service.
I have set the *Always on* feature to true.
When I log the requests, I see that Azure *Always on* requests are coming every 5 minutes.

[image: always on logs]

My usage with API is HTTPS but *Always on* requests are sending with HTTP. I don't know if this is the case

[image: azure vs usage logs]

For the first request, it is sometimes 10 seconds, but after the first request, it is around 100ms.

What is missing here?

I have logged the durations:
[image: durations]

Comment: Please add some (relevant) code to enable us to help you. Without any code, this is going to be a tough nut to crack. Refer to [ask] and provide a [example].

Comment: Which part of code do you want to see? I don't know which piece of code to share.

Comment: It looks like it's all in the `SubscriptionController`. Might be the query you're executing is simply taking too much time? Again, please provide us with (relevant) code, like the `Index` action or the `SubscriptionInfo` action on the `SubscriptionController`.

Comment: These are the regular durations of endpoints. The problem occurs rarely after some time period at the first request. Do you still think it is code related? https://imgur.com/a/hDf7r32

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few reasons why this might be the case:

1. You're connecting to resources that take time connecting to the first time
2. Some information is being cached and needs to be read the first time
3. There is initialization code present
4. Lazy instantiation of (static/singleton) instances
5. ... other ...

Add some logging to your application, maybe enable Application Insights if you haven't done so already and go try to find the culprit.

Comment: I have added durations logs, does it mean anything?

Comment: I dont think connectting a resource will take time. And there is no cache. There is no initialization process. There is no lazy instantiations. So it must be something else.